# tcpdf: poor image quality

Tags: image, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to create PDF files converted from HTML input using it's writeHTML() function. However, images within the PDF have poor quality, while the original images have a high quality (as expected). The images are in PNG format. I already tried to use SetJPEGQuality(100),  but that had no effect.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 8):

Try using this:

```
$pdf->setImageScale(1.53);
```

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/forums/forum/435311/topic/4831671

Comment: When using HTML-input, this seems to scale element dimensions as well, which results in broken tables and layouts. :(

Answer (score 4):

When using HTML to generate your PDFs you need to manually calculate the images dimensions by dividing it's original width and height by `1.53` and set the result as attributes.

For example, an image with dimensions of 200x100 pixels will become:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="131" height="65" />
```

This is a nasty workaround and doesn't completely remove the blur, but the result is much better than without any scaling.

Comment: Hi, when you say 200x100 you are referring to mm, right?

Comment: @freeloader No, I meant pixels. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try To convert your Image to JPG or JPEG first. Until Now, I DOnt have a problem to convert image with TCPDF. I Think TCPDF is powerfull, because it can convert arabic language too. I HAve try convert arabic font with fpdf n it still fail

Answer (score 0):

Little Up.

I'd same quality problem and I solved it...
When you save your picture, do it in 8bits instead of 24bits and you will see a "beautiful anti-aliasing".